# Run Time Error 3464: Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form in Access 2010 with Two text boxes(AIPIDTxt to enter the search criteria and AIPResultTxt to display results) and a Button(Search button). I also have a Table Table1 in Access. When I click the Search Button, I need to execute a query whose criteria is in AIPIDTxt Textbox in the form, store the result in a recordset and display the results in the textbox AIPResultTxt. So I typed in the following VBA Code in the Button Event handler.

```
Private Sub SearchB_Click()

Dim localConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim query As String
Dim aipid_rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
Set localConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
MsgBox "Local Connection successful"
query = "SELECT [AIP Name] FROM [Table1] WHERE [AIP ID]= 
" & [Forms]![AIPIDSearchF]![AIPIDTxt] & ""
Set aipid_rs = db.OpenRecordset(query)
Me.AIPResultTxt.Text = aipid_rs![AIP Name]
End Sub
```

But when I click the button I get Local Connection Successful Message Box and then a Run Time Error 3464 in the line:

```
Set aipid_rs= db.OpenRecordset(query)
```

I have searched for similar errors and made corrections. But the error keeps coming. Is there something wrong with my query? Couldn't figure out the error. The table is a local table. So I can directly give [Table1] and field names in the query in vba. Tried adding delimiters because the fields are text fields. But that didn't work as well. I could not give the following query as well:

```
query = "SELECT [AIP Name] FROM [Table1] WHERE [AIP ID]= " & [Forms]![AIPIDSearchF]!
[AIPIDTxt].Text & ""
```

This gave me a run time error stating text cannot be referenced from controls that have lost focus. My criteria is text in the text box. The text box loses focus when i click the button. But when I googled for the error, solutions were to remove ".Text". So, I ended up with the above query. Do not know what is wrong with the line:

```
Set aipid_rs= db.OpenRecordset(query)
```

Comment: What is the data type of column "AIP_ID"?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: AIP ID is Text data type

Comment: You need to put quotes around your query value.

Comment: @TimWilliams: I gave this:                                                        query = "SELECT [AIP Name] FROM [ACH] WHERE [AIP ID]= '" + [Forms]![AIPIDSearchF]![AIPIDTxt] + "'"                                     Set aip_rs = db.OpenRecordset(query)
Me.AIPResultTxt.SetFocus
Me.AIPResultTxt = aipid_rs![AIP Name] The run time error 3464 is gone. But i get RunTime Error 91: Object Variable or With Block not set

Comment: Maybe there are no results?

Comment: Is your form open/active when the query is run?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have more than one problem with that code.  But Access complains about only the first problem it finds.  Look again at these 2 lines ...

```vb
Dim aipid_rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set aipid_rs = db.OpenRecordset(query)
```

`OpenRecordset` is a DAO method which returns a DAO recordset.  But the code attempts to assign it to `aipid_rs` which was declared `As ADODB.Recordset`.  Those recordset types are not compatible.

There is an ADO connection object variable, *localConnection*, which is not used for anything later.  Although it doesn't trigger an error, it's just not useful.  And actually I don't see any reason to use anything from ADO for this task.

I suggest you try this version of your code ...

```vb
'Dim localConnection As ADODB.Connection
'Dim query As String ' query is a reserved word
Dim strQuery As String
'Dim aipid_rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim aipid_rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
'Set localConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
'MsgBox "Local Connection successful"
' you said [AIP ID] is text type, so include quotes around 
' the text box value
strQuery = "SELECT [AIP Name] FROM [Table1] WHERE [AIP ID]= '" & _
    [Forms]![AIPIDSearchF]![AIPIDTxt] & "'"
Debug.Print strQuery
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDebugWindow
Set aipid_rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
'Me.AIPResultTxt.Text = aipid_rs![AIP Name] ' .Text property is only
    ' available when control has focus; it will trigger 
    ' an error at any other time                           
Me.AIPResultTxt.Value = aipid_rs![AIP Name]
```

Note `Debug.Print strQuery` will display the text of the `SELECT` statement in the Immediate window, and `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDebugWindow` opens the Immediate window.  If you still have a problem with the query, copy the statement text and paste it into SQL View of a new query for testing.

Finally I'm curious whether this might give you what you need with much less code ...

```vb
Private Sub SearchB_Click()
    Me.AIPResultTxt.Value = DLookup("[AIP Name]", "Table1", _
        "[AIP ID]='" & Me.AIPIDTxt & "'")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an ADO recordset, therefore your open syntax is incorrect. The following should work for you (except you may get an error setting the text if the control doesn't have focus...)

```
Dim localConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim query           As String
Dim aipid_rs        As ADODB.Recordset
Dim db              As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
Set localConnection = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
MsgBox "Local Connection successful"
query = "SELECT [AIP Name] FROM [Table1] WHERE [AIP ID]= '" & [Forms]![AIPIDSearchF]![AIPIDTxt] & "'"
'Set aipid_rs = db.OpenRecordset(query)
Set aipid_rs = New ADODB.Recordset
aipid_rs.Open query, localConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
If Not aipid_rs.EOF Then
    Me.AIPResultTxt.Text = aipid_rs![AIP Name]
Else
    MsgBox "No records!!"
End If
aipid_rs.Close
Set aipid_rs = Nothing
localConnection.Close
Set localConnection = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I have been searching for a simple search element for quite awhile...
I have tried using subforms and I have tried recordsets. All of these have given me the information. But not the compactness I was looking for, thanks!!!

using the DOA stuf is great but not for my application.
using the above:

`Me.AIPResultTxt.Value = DLookup("[AIP Name]", "Table1", _
        "[AIP ID]='" & Me.AIPIDTxt & "'")`

I have the compactness of code I was looking for...
THanks!!!
T